# Timelocked bribing

Tags: mining-theory, attack, hash-time-locked-contract, censorship-resistance, miner-extractable-value

Did anyone observe any instance of [Timelocked Bribing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/774) in Bitcoin transaction? Are there any specific articles that points out that the attack has been mounted in reality?